# The hierarchy of operations, a convention?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

I know that I have already asked a question about it, but reviewing the group theory, the question arises: does the group theory support the hierarchy of arithmetic operations? I ask why we could say:

\begin{equation}
8\div2(2+2) = 8*2^{-1}*(2+2)
\end{equation}

The above seems correct to me if I see the set of rational numbers as a group. I would greatly appreciate your comments on this, or if the hierarchy of operations is still a convention at the end of the story.

Comment: Yes, $8\div 2=8\cdot 2^{-1}$, but I fail to understand what (if anything) this has to do with "hierarchy of operations". Can you please explain?

Comment: I ask, because I have seen that there is always discussion, if the arithmetic operations are done from left to right or from right to left for operations of the same order.

Comment: My personal advice: completely abandon the symbol $÷$. It is never used in actual mathematics, and will just confuse people in these situations, precisely because no one will be sure if you mean it to be more or less binding than the product.

Comment: Well, @BML *that* is a convention, and the established one is: operations of the same priority are done left-to-right *except* for exponentiation, where they are done right-to-left. This has nothing to do with group theory (or any other serious algebra): it is just a convention *how* we write things (as opposed to *what* is written). If in doubt, put parentheses to make it clear. There isn't much more to it.

Comment: Also in the riddle you've posted, the issue is *not* whether you do multiplication and division left-to-right or righ-to-left, but whether the "implied" multiplication $2(2+2)$ is considered of *higher priority* than both the explicit multiplication and division (because, if yes, it needs to be done first!). So, is $2x$ a different multiplication than $2\times x$? For most part I don't care, I will put parentheses where needed so that this does not even arise as a problem, but in math education one should take a firm stance that this is just the ordinary multiplication...

Comment: ... and has no special higher priority - or otherwise we will never manage to teach kids the BIDMAS/PEMDAS rules!